# Verificar itens duplicados e atualizar uma coluna em todos menos um

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Tenho uma tabela de produtos que trazem informações de um XML, e outra tabela no sistema que basicamente recebe esses produtos após aprovação (temos uma interface para definir o que entra ou não, basicamente alterando um valor no produto para que ele não fique visível mas continue na base). Os produtos que entram do XML muitas vezes trazem diversos itens similares, mudam apenas alguns parâmetros no SKU do produto, devido diferença de tamanho das roupas, conforme o exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria de fazer é o seguinte:

Como posso selecionar todos os resultados duplicados, menos um deles, e atualizar a coluna importado destes que o select trouxer. O importado como 0 esconde o produto da fila de aprovação, assim a fila não vai mostrar varias vezes o mesmo produto que basicamente só tem o SKU diferente.

Valeu galera.

Comment: tentei utilizar a query <pre>UPDATE sis_produto_xml WHERE sku NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS lastid, nome FROM sis_produto_xml WHERE nome IN ( SELECT nome FROM sis_produto_xml GROUP BY nome HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) GROUP BY nome) SET importado = 1;</pre> mas é apresentada falha.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que um `GROUP BY` funcionaria, algo como:

```
UPDATE tabela SET importado = 1 WHERE sku <> FIRST(sku) GROUP BY nome
```

Só testa com um SELECT antes pra ver se está selecionando os registros certos

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE sku <> FIRST(sku) GROUP BY nome
```

Comment: Testei aqui mas apresentou um erro no <>, estou dando uma olhada

Comment: testei aqui mas não deu certo não. valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O update abaixo por mais que pareça extenso ele é eficaz para o objetivo questionado.

```sql
UPDATE
    demo
SET
    importado = 0
WHERE
    sku NOT IN -- Atualizará os demais sku das duplicações
(
  SELECT 
    Max(x.sku) -- Busco o maior SKU dentre os duplicados, assim selecionando somente um de cada duplicacao
  FROM 
    demo x 
  WHERE 
    EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT
        count(1)
      FROM
        demo y
      WHERE 
          x.name = y.name
      GROUP BY y.name
      HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    )
  GROUP BY x.name
)
AND name IN -- Somente os nomes com duplicações serão atualizados
(
  SELECT
    x.name
  FROM
      demo x
  WHERE
    EXISTS
      (
      SELECT count(1) from demo y
      WHERE 
        x.name = y.name
      GROUP BY y.name
      HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    )
)
```